# Workaround for enoent error from Erlang's Common Test on Windows?

Tags: testing, erlang, tdd

When using Common Test with Erlang on Windows, I run into a lot of bugs with Common Test and Erlang. For one, if there are any spaces in the project's path, Common Test often fails outright. To workaround this, I moved the project to a path with no spaces (but I really wish the devs would fix the libraries so they work better on Windows). Now, I got Common Test to mostly run, except it won't print out the HTML report at the end. This is the error I get after the tests run:

```
Testing myapp.ebin: EXIT, reason {
{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
              [{test_server_ctrl,start_minor_log_file1,4,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},{line,1959}]},
               {test_server_ctrl,run_test_case1,11,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},{line,3761}]},
               {test_server_ctrl,run_test_cases_loop,5,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},{line,3032}]},
               {test_server_ctrl,run_test_cases,3,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},{line,2294}]},
               {test_server_ctrl,ts_tc,3,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},{line,1434}]},
               {test_server_ctrl,init_tester,9,
                                 [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                  {line,1401}]}]}
```

This happened in sometimes in Erlang R15 and older if the test function names were either too long or had too many underscores in the name (which I suspect is also a bug) or when too many tests failed (which means Common Test is useless to me for TDD). But now it happens on every ct:run from Common Test in R15B01. Does anyone know how I can workaround this? Has anyone had any success with TDD and Common Test on Windows?

Comment: could you please attach a minimal reproducible example of the SUITE and the version of windows+common_test that you are running?

Comment: I'm running Windows XP SP3 32-bit. The version of Common Test is the one that comes with R15B01, which is Common Test 1.6.1. As far as a reproducible example, unfortunately I'm using this at work so I can't show the code, so I'll see if there is some smaller example that will reproduce this. But the problem is that Common Test working or not working seems to be caused by the smallest differences (based on my experiences). I'm new to stackoverflow, can you attach code that is longer than these comment boxes allow? If not, I'm not sure if I can reproduce it. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: You might want to use something like http://ideone.com/ or edit your post above with the relevant code. if nothing else I'd suggest sending a bug report (With the example suite) to the erlang-patchet mailing list

Comment: I've been poking and prodding at it more, and I think maybe the kind of testing I'm doing is probably not handled well by Common Test. I'm basically sending messages to thousands of processes and verifying the result for every process. This happens several times per test case. If a test fails, it tends to cause thousands of errors to spit information to stdout very rapidly, which is being captured by Common Test and perhaps overloading it.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that I also see in the Common Test logs that makes me think this: === Ended at 2012-04-27 15:52:54
=== location {ct_framework,end_tc}
=== reason = {error,
                     {ct_framework,end_tc,
                         {timeout,
                             {gen_event,call,
                                 [error_logger,cth_log_redirect,flush]}}}}

Answer (score 0):

Given the last comment you might want to disable the buildin_hooks. You can do this by passing the following to ct:run/1 or ct_run

```
{enable_builtin_hooks,false}
```

That should disable the cth_log_redirect hook and maybe solve your problem during overload.